# Forward download to Raspberry (from Mac / Chrome)

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I am frequently downloading large files in my browser (Chrome on Mac). I'd like to be able to shut down my computer and continue the download. Currently, I halt the download, scp the incomplete file over to my RPI, copy the download URL from Chrome://downloads, ssh to my RPI and do wget -c '#url' -O 'file'. Then, next day, I scp the file over. This is kind of too complicated. Is there a simple way (plugin?) to just directly trigger the download on my RPI? Maybe Chrome talking to Chromium?

---

What i'm doing currently (status quo)

```
var h=require('http');
var wget = require('node-wget');
var url = require('url');

var server=h.createServer(function (req, res) {

    setTimeout(function () {
      var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
      var query = url_parts.query;
      var u = query.u;
      wget(''+u+'');
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end(u+' received');
    }, 100);


});
server.listen(1200);
```

and 'Custom right-click menu extension for chrome'

```
var query;
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:1200/?u=%s";
if (crmAPI.getSelection()) {
    query = crmAPI.getSelection();
} else {
    query = window.prompt('Please enter a search query');
}
if (query) {
    window.open(url.replace(/%s/g,query), '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Maybe some node.js server on RPI?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloaders/lfjamigppmepikjlacjdpgjaiojdjhoj/related could be used to trigger a script...

Comment: I believe that I have created to a script to (hopefully) work with that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script with this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloaders/lfjamigppmepikjlacjdpgjaiojdjhoj/

```
C:\path\to\ssh.exe local@host.com && cd "/where/to/download" && wget -c --referer="%r" "%u"
```

You will need to setup up key-based logins with no password on your Pi.

Comment: will try this. sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: @user2707001 I only problem I can see is when you try to download a login protected file, in which case you need to download the file manually with [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg) and `wget --options --load-cookies="/path/to/cookies.txt"`

Comment: Cannot get the script to work unfortunately. Is there a trick? It just does nothing.

Comment: @user2707001 try again after doing this: http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: that's not the issue; the chrome script doesn't work - it just does nothing. My ssh etc. pp. is just fine